# How does the interaction between rigidbody2d.movePosition and rigidbody2d.AddForce works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to use the .AddForce code alongside the .movePosition one, but the .movePosition making the .AddForce do nothing. I think is because the line: " Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, 0);" but I really don't know how to fix it. The .AddForce code works as inteded by itself.

Edit: posted full code.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CompletePlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float speed;                //Floating point variable to store the player's movement speed.
public float jumpforce;
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;        //Store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component required to use 2D Physics.

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Get and store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component so that we can access it.
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}


//FixedUpdate is called at a fixed interval and is independent of frame rate. Put physics code here.
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Jump();

    //Store the current horizontal input in the float moveHorizontal.
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    //Store the current vertical input in the float moveVertical.

    //Use the two store floats to create a new Vector2 variable movement.
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, 0);

    //Call the AddForce function of our Rigidbody2D rb2d supplying movement multiplied by speed to move our player.
    rb2d.MovePosition ((Vector2)transform.position + (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime));

}
void Jump(){
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical")){
    rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpforce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't even show the `AddForce` code here. AddForce will apply a force to an object where as MovePosition will move the object using interpolation. Seems like MovePosition will simply overwrite the applied force

Comment: Oh, yes sorry. Will edit it now. Thanks for replying! The answer is helpful thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the names say:

[`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)

> Moves the rigidbody to the specified position by **calculating the appropriate linear velocity** required to move the rigidbody to that position during the next physics update. During the move, neither gravity or linear drag will affect the body.

[`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html)

> Adds a force to the `Rigidbody`
>
> The force is specified as two separate components in the X and Y directions (there is no Z direction in 2D physics). The object will be accelerated by the force according to the law force = mass x acceleration - the larger the mass, the greater the force required to accelerate to a given speed.

So according to the mass and friction of the object it causes it to move with a certain velocity according to the physics.

---

Mixing both makes not much sense since `MovePosition` is usually used for `isKinematic` rigidbodies, so ones that are fully controlled via script while `AddForce` only has effect on **not** `isKinematic` ones, thus fully controlled by physics alone; by mixing both you don't give `AddForce` a chance to work since you overwrite the linear velocity of the rigodbody by using `MovePosition` which adjusts an absolute velocity to the Rigidbody thus completely overruling the `AddForce`.

```
rb2d.MovePosition (transform.position + (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

this target position you want it to move towards has always the same `Y` as `transform.position.y` so you basically nail your object to that height.

---

However, if you think about it, all physics actions have one thing in common: In the end they are all different ways to under the hood apply a certain **velocity** to the rigodbody.

So instead of letting these methods calculate that velocity you could instead rather directly change the [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) yourself and thereby let `AddForce` fully control the `Y` velocity while you control only `X` component:

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rb2d.velocity.y);
```